# Arial for commercial use

Tags: font-licensing

I'm creating a streetwear brand and I was wondering if I can use the font Arial on my t-shirts. I can't find much about its commercial use.

Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/font-faq

This Microsoft's publication covers your case if you asked about that Arial which is shipped with Windows. It says that you can well create commercial products which are printed or otherwise outputted as long as you do not try to include font files itself. There is a special clause for embedding font files to a document file, but wearable clothes are not such documents (It says that those document files must be made with certain allowed programs such as Word, which render the embedded fonts unusable for other purposes)

There's some things which are explicitly forbidden

- distributing font files
- designing or generating commercial products with home- or student versions of software
- uploading font files to websites or converting them to web-font formats

The last limitation prevents for example use in online designing applications. For them one must purchase Arial version which is licensed for web usage.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you can use any font purchased legally on any final product. In this case a Tshirt... or a magazine, or a book.

What you can not do with a font is re-sell it, this is, sell the TTF or OTF file or redistribute it.